# Regex in Notepad++ to Find-Replace or Remove Partial Strings

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++, regex-group

This is adapted from an online dataset referencing "Customer Complaints". The data was modified in Excel and Notepad++. This manipulation produced an "extra" set of quotes directly following each "index digit" [1,2,3 ...] directly after the string, "VALUES (X". I would like to remove only this "extra quotes" and maintain the sequential index numbers, which range from a single digit to a number having five digits. This is in preparation to working with a proprietary database having 1.35 million lines of code.

---

This rather clumsy adaptation of Regex will "find" a string containing the quotes but a "replace" code which maintains the indexing numbers eludes me. Any help would be appreciated.

REGEX

```
\s\(([0-9])",|\s\(([0-9][0-9])",|\s\(([0-9][0-9][0-9])",|\s\(([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])",|\s\(([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])",
```

DATA STRINGS

```
INSERT INTO Complaints VALUES (1","2013-07-29","consumer loan","managing the loan or lease","Wells Fargo & Company","VA","24540","phone","2013-07-30","closed with explanation","468882");

INSERT INTO Complaints VALUES (2","2013-07-29","bank account or service","using a debit or ATM card","Wells Fargo & Company","CA","95992","web","2013-07-31","closed with explanation","468889");

INSERT INTO Complaints VALUES (3","2013-07-29","bank account or service","account opening, closing, or management","Santander Bank US","NY","10065","fax","2013-07-31","closed","468879");
```

Comment: Pro tip: `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` is just the same as `\d{5}`.

Comment: Emma: Thanks for the reply. Much appreciated ...!

Answer (score 1):

Find `VALUES \((\d+)"` - the inner parentheses will capture the digits (`\d`) one or more times (`+`) until a `"` is encountered.

You can then  replace with `VALUES \($1` where `$1` is the corresponding captured value.

Comment: The various suggestions here are first rate! Do any of you produce videos ... perhaps on YouTube on the topic of Regex? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `VALUES\h*\(\d+\K"`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
VALUES      # literally
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
\(          # opening parenthesis
\d+         # 1 or more digits
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
"           # a double quote
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Toto: The original question was mine. I appreciate the reply and did not "down vote" your effort. I feel this site has more worth than simply as "one more anonymous, gamified platform on the Internet". Thanks again ... your explanation was exemplary!

Comment: Your format is excellent and this specific reply was critical.  [Wayne]